# How to use ByteBuffer in a session bean class that is remote?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cassandra, cql

We are using `cassandra` for some of our data needs. There is one `column family`(table) which has one column of type `blob`.

According to the [`datastax` documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/1.0/java-driver/reference/javaClass2Cql3Datatypes_r.html), datatype for cql blob is `java.nio.ByteBuffer`.

We have a class for object mapping to cassandra table let us say SampleEntity and it's defined as below

```
        @Table(name="sampletable", keyspace="main")
        public class SampleEntity{
             @Column("id")
             private UUID id;

             @Column("data")
             private ByteBuffer complexData;

             //...getters and setters
        }
```

We have a stateless session bean class(remote ejb) which has code to persist the objects to database using entity manager. This class implements an interface annotated with @Remote (javax.ejb.Remote).

```
     @stateless
     public class SampleEntityBean implements SampleEntityBeanRemote{

         //inject entity manager
         .... SomeDatatype entityManager

         UUID createEntity(SampleEntity entity){
                 entityManager.persist(entity);
         }

     }
```

Now, we use SampleEntityBean in many places in our application by injecting it using @EJB annotation. So, this means this method is called remotely using RMI underhood.

The problem is ByteBuffer is not serializable and it's giving `Unable to marshal ejb parameters` caused by `Not serializable exception: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer`.

That means, on one hand I require `ByteBuffer` for `blob` and on the other hand I may not use this since it's not serializable.

So, is there any way to work around this in a standard way?

Is there any way I can use some different datatype (like `byte[]`) and perhaps use an annotation on it to convert into `ByteBuffer` on the last minute?

Comment: Somebody please help

Answer (score 1):

There is no way as far as I know. The mapping API uses the field type not the getters/setters so you couldn't store it as a byte[] but have the getter return a ByteBuffer. Looks like you'll need to use two different DTOs, one for the Cassandra driver, one for your EJBs.

Taking a look at the JIRA for the driver someone else has already requested custom serialisation: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-566 so go and vote for that :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm going with two field approach. One for column mapping and one for the rest. I kept one as transient and the other as @Transient. We have to handle the conversion either in the setters and getters or implement writeObject and readObject methods in the entity class. I will post this as an answer for future visitors.